# Restrict the use of an API in Laravel to a single application

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I have an **API** in **Laravel** that only consume in my frontend. The problem that arises for me is **how to authorize the use of the API to a single application** without revealing information that other applications may apply to make use of it (an example of this would be sending a header, which can be obtained and replicated).

I understand that with Passport I can get it but it seems to me to be a very sophisticated solution for a case where I will only need an authorization and I would just like to know where to look since I can't find anything. *Sorry for my bad English.*

Comment: Have your tried using JWT?

Comment: The problem I have is that I can use anything, but if an application user copies the token (consulting the headers sent from the inspector) and simply uses postman, it could already make API requests if I'm not mistaken

Comment: It's pretty hard to gain access to an access token when the entity is not operating the same consumption device/ relying party especially with HTTPS enforced. But you can read this article: https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/OAuth%202.0%20Proof-of-Possession%20%28PoP%29%20Security%20Architecture